# In BigQuery, concatenate columns in sorted order based on 2nd table of values

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following reproducible example, as the title may not be 100% clear and the example should help:

```
with
  
  player_heights as (
    select 'joe' as name, 0.35 as height union all
    select 'tom' as name, 0.75 as height union all
    select 'nick' as name, 0.2 as height union all
    select 'sal' as name, 1.2 as height union all
    select 'chris' as name, 0.5 as height union all
    select 'cob' as name, null as height union all
    select 'jeff' as name, 1.1 as height union all
    select 'pob' as name, 0.71 as height
  ),
  
  players_table as (
    select 'joe' as p1, 'tom' as p2, 'nick' as p3, 'sal' as p4, 'chris' as p5, 0.35 as h1, 0.75 as h2, 0.2 as h3, 1.2 as h4, 0.5 as h5 union all
    select 'joe' as p1, 'nick' as p2, 'cob' as p3, 'jeff' as p4, 'pob' as p5, 0.35 as h1, 0.2 as h2, null as h3, 1.1 as h4, 0.71 as h5 union all
    select 'tom' as p1, 'chris' as p2, 'sal' as p3, 'jeff' as p4, 'pob' as p5, 0.75 as h1, 0.5 as h2, 1.2 as h3, 1.1 as h4, 0.71 as h5
  )
  

select
  concat(p1, '-', p2, '-', p3, '-', p4, '-', p5) as players
  ,* 
from players_table
```

[image: ge add]

Each person is associated with a height, from the `player_heights` table. In `players_table`, each row has 5 persons, and each of their heights has been joined onto the table already.

For each row in `players_table`, the 5 players need to be concatenated into a single string. The challenge is that these players should be sorted **based on their height**, from smallest to largest, with `null` height person at the end of the concatenated string. Currently, the heights are not being accounted for in the basic `concat` I'm using. The correct output for the `players` column in the second row would then be `nick-joe-pob-jeff-cob`.

### Edit

I've thought about using a nested `case when` statement, however with 5 persons there are 120 possible orderings of players, and that seems like far too many for a `case when`

### Edit 2

If this is not possible, then another solution that could work would be to sort the persons alphabetically before `concat`. This is not ideal but may be simpler.

### Update

The following column added to the final select `ARRAY(SELECT x FROM UNNEST(array<string>[p1, p2, p3, p4, p5]) AS x ORDER BY x) AS arr2` does create an array from the 5 string columns, and then sorts them. So this is moving in the right direction, but I have no way yet to use the additional height values here.

```
select
  *
  ,array_to_string(
    array(select x from unnest(array[p1, p2, p3, p4, p5]) as x order by x),
    '-'
  ) as players
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL 
WITH players_table AS (
  SELECT 'joe' AS p1, 'tom' AS p2, 'nick' AS p3, 'sal' AS p4, 'chris' AS p5, 0.35 AS h1, 0.75 AS h2, 0.2 AS h3, 1.2 AS h4, 0.5 AS h5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'joe' AS p1, 'nick' AS p2, 'cob' AS p3, 'jeff' AS p4, 'pob' AS p5, 0.35 AS h1, 0.2 AS h2, NULL AS h3, 1.1 AS h4, 0.71 AS h5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'tom' AS p1, 'chris' AS p2, 'sal' AS p3, 'jeff' AS p4, 'pob' AS p5, 0.75 AS h1, 0.5 AS h2, 1.2 AS h3, 1.1 AS h4, 0.71 AS h5
)
SELECT STRING_AGG(p, '-' ORDER BY h) AS players, 
  ANY_VALUE(t).*
FROM players_table t
LEFT JOIN UNNEST([p1, p2, p3, p4, p5]) p WITH OFFSET
LEFT JOIN UNNEST([h1, h2, h3, h4, h5]) h WITH OFFSET
USING(OFFSET)
GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', t)
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Something about this is significantly slowing down a query of mine that works on a 20GB table, from 2 minutes to 8 minutes. Does this approach have some very expensive calculation?

Comment: from what I understand, your query does not do what you need it to do - while query in my answer does it! - right? so it is hard to compare queries which do different things - meantime, I will think more on your case and will post new solution if will find more optimal one :o)

Comment: @Canovice - see optimized version in new answer. there might/should be slightly better performance - but overall it still as expensive as your logic requires

Answer (score 1):

Below is optimized version

```
#standardSQL 
WITH players_table AS (
  SELECT 'joe' AS p1, 'tom' AS p2, 'nick' AS p3, 'sal' AS p4, 'chris' AS p5, 0.35 AS h1, 0.75 AS h2, 0.2 AS h3, 1.2 AS h4, 0.5 AS h5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'joe' AS p1, 'nick' AS p2, 'cob' AS p3, 'jeff' AS p4, 'pob' AS p5, 0.35 AS h1, 0.2 AS h2, NULL AS h3, 1.1 AS h4, 0.71 AS h5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'tom' AS p1, 'chris' AS p2, 'sal' AS p3, 'jeff' AS p4, 'pob' AS p5, 0.75 AS h1, 0.5 AS h2, 1.2 AS h3, 1.1 AS h4, 0.71 AS h5
)
SELECT (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(p, '-' ORDER BY h)
    FROM UNNEST([p1, p2, p3, p4, p5]) p WITH OFFSET
    LEFT JOIN UNNEST([h1, h2, h3, h4, h5]) h WITH OFFSET
    USING(OFFSET)
  ) AS players, *
FROM players_table
```

Comment: I never commented on this optimized version, but it is notably faster in my query for some reason. Rather than increase my query time by a factor of 4x, it only increases the query time by ~40%, which is still a meaningful slow down (60 --> 90 secs), but is much much better while achieving the desired results.